# How to force update the fill color of existing elements in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, refresh

I draw a matrix using d3, color fills in each cell according to its value. Function like this:

```
var redVal = 5000,
    greenVal = 2000;

var color = function (rtt) {
    if (rtt === undefined) {
        return "white";
    }

    if (rtt <= greenVal) {
        return "green";
    } else if (rtt <= redVal) {
        return "yellow";
    } else {
        return "red";
    }
};

heatMap.data(matrix, function (d) { return d.x + ":" + d.y; })
       .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.m_Item3); })
```

Now I changed redVal and greenVal, how to force each cell update its fill color? I can achieve by something like this : `d3.selectAll().data(matrix).style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.m_Item3); })`, but I am expecting more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you asked for a more *elegant* way, you should use a scale, like [`scaleThreshold`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleThreshold):

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([2000, 5000])
    .range(["green", "yellow", "red"]);
```

According to the API:

> The values are typically numbers, but any naturally ordered values (such as strings) will work; a threshold scale can be used to encode any type that is ordered. If the number of values in the scale’s range is N+1, the number of values in the scale’s domain must be N.

So, we have 2 values in the domain and 3 in the range. If the value passed for the scale is less than 2000, it will return `green`. Between 2000 and 5000 will return `yellow`, and over 5000 will it will return `red`.

After that, checking for `undefined` with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
.style("fill", function (d) { return d ? color(d) : "white"});
```

See this demo showing how the threshold scale works:

```js
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([2000, 5000])
    .range(["green", "yellow", "red"]);

console.log("the color for 400 is " + color(400));
console.log("the color for 1500 is " + color(1500));
console.log("the color for 3200 is " + color(3200));
console.log("the color for 7000 is " + color(7000));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: to update the colour of the rectangles, change the `domain` with your variables and fill the rects again:

```
color.domain([greenVal, redVal]);
d3.selectAll("rect").style("fill", function (d) { 
    return color(d.m_Item3);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, glad to learn the usage of scaleThreshold. But I think you didn't get my question. My problem is, the threshold 2000, 5000 could be changed by user, if user changes say 2000 to 1000, I want to refresh each cell's fill color.

Comment: You could simply use variables in the domain, like `.domain([greenVal, redVal]);`, the same way you did in your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, maybe not the most elegant way:

```
$("#green").change(function () {
    greenVal = $("#green").val();
    redVal = $("#red").val();
    if (greenVal > redVal) {
        greenVal = redVal;
        $("#green").val(greenVal);
    }

    // call .style again with same callback to do refresh.
    d3.selectAll("rect").style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.m_Item3); });
});
```